# Adding barcode in Event confirmation email

Tags: civievent

We want to add Qr code in event email.

Is there any way we can add QR code in Event registration confirmation email?

Comment: I expect this will be voted down as it seems you haven't searched existing tickets on this and/or explained why your question is different to those ones

Comment: I can't find any ticket that explain how to do what Sushant want - i.e. QR code in the receipt. The only thing that seems possible is to print labels with QR code on them, which is quite different because you still need to search in hundreds / thousands of name to get the proper QR at registration. I would be interested if anyone has an answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this forum post : https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=23767.0 which seems to propose a solution based on a old version of CiviCRM but the method is still valid in principle :

- either using an existing service on the web (https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes?csw=1) or configure your own that generate a QR code image
- calling the url from within the src image in your template : `<img src="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=120x120&chl={$participantID}&choe=UTF-8" alt="Ticket ID: {$participantID}">`